# Lambda syntax in MongoDb driver to update an array element in a document

Tags: c#, mongodb, lambda

I'm using MongoDb C# driver in my application and I need to update a sub-item in my document. I found the way doing something like this:

```
var query = Query<User>.ElemMatch(_=>_.Item, qb=>qb.EQ(x => x.Valid,false));

var update = Update.Set("Item.$.Valid", true); <-- can I use lambda here?

var result = collection.Update(query, update);
```

Now I want to ask you: Can I use lambda syntax to remove the fixed string `"Item.$.Valid"` enabling compile-time check (like `Update<Item>.Set(x=>x...`)?

Inside driver source code I've found nothing about this!

Comment: It's an interesting question  :-)

Comment: @daniele3004 you can upvote to indicate that

Answer (score 2):

Not right now. This is the JIRA ticket for it. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-588

Coming up with a good syntax for this without doubling all the helper methods is difficult. We are completely open to suggestions, so please comment on the JIRA ticket if you have some.